# preserving text format php for UserData

Tags: php, string, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

My problem seems simple but I am stuck.

I have a template file which has content like below:

```
#!/bin/sh 
    sudo -s;
    touch /tmp/{{key}}
```

My requirement is I have to read this file replace the `key`     with some value and then pass to `UserData` as input to `AWS PHP sdk` .

How after running

```
$key = "{{key}}";
$value ="test1.txt";
$fileContent = file_get_contents($templatePath);
str_replace("{{" . $key . "}}", "$value", $fileContent);
```

to the above file content the format is lost. It generates something like as follows

```
#!/bin/sh sudo -s;touch /tmp/test1.txt
```

I lost all the format and the SDK does not understand it as bash script

Comment: you need to show how you are reading and writing to that file

Comment: Do you mean that line feeds get stripped? Unless I'm missing something, nothing in the code you've shared should do that.

Comment: I mean the format is not preserved. It comes to a single line

Comment: How is it different from line feeds getting stripped? Whatever, it isn't reproducible with the code you've shared. Perhaps you're uploading the template with an FTP client that has Windows-to-Unix line end conversion enabled, running the code in a Unix server and then opening the resulting file with Windows notepad.